# Seeking Guidance on Constrained Input Modeling for Soil Moisture Correction Using Rainfall Observations

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, spatial, image-processing, inverse-prediction

I find myself immersed in the intricacies of working with 2D modeled fields (images) representing soil moisture in regions where direct observations are unfortunately absent. However, there is a silver lining—I possess observational data for rainfall within the same geographic areas. My primary objective is to elevate the precision of soil moisture predictions by integrating rainfall observations as a crucial constraining factor.

My current contemplation revolves around the adoption of a CNN regression approach for my inverse modeling problem. In this envisioned model, the input comprises the modeled soil images, while the output corresponds to the rainfall values across various time steps. It's noteworthy that this application deviates from conventional CNN models; here, the focus is on refining the accuracy of soil moisture predictions (inputs) rather than generating predictions for rainfall (outputs).

This methodology appears reminiscent of inverse modeling or Bayesian models. I am eager to seek your valuable insights and expertise, particularly if you can provide suggestions for alternative models or methodologies that might be better suited to my purpose.

I express my gratitude in advance for your contributions.